# How do I setup jest for a sub-module in my app?

Tags: unit-testing, enzyme, jestjs

I'm writing my tests in jest with enzyme. We've already setup jest with our app. We have different submodules in our app as:

```
- app
  - submodule1
  - submodule2
  - submodule3 etc.
```

Now, we are moving one `submodule` in our app. The thing is which are globally putting `jQuery` etc. in our app so that if any submodule needs it then it can take that from global. We've specified the path for them as well. A submodule was using different version of `jQuery` and my submodule is using different version of `jQuery`. So, we thought of writing tests with respect to module. I want to ask whether it is possible and if it is how do I setup `jest.config` for each submodule and what will be the scripts in my package.json?

Comment: i am facing same issue plz help us...